# Is it possible to merge two SQL (MS Access) queries into one?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I was wondering whether it was possible to merge two queries into one?
I have two SQL queries. The first outputs the Average Final Mark for a Student in year one. The second outputs the Average Final Mark for a student in Year 3.

I've tried using UNION but unfortunately, it just shifts everything into one column. I'm using SQL through MS Access.

1st Query:

```
SELECT Marks.Student_ID AS Year, SUM(Final_Mark)/COUNT(Marks.Student_ID) AS Year_1_Marks
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Marks.Year_Taken = 1 AND Students.Student_ID IN
(SELECT Marks.Student_ID
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID) 
GROUP BY Marks.Student_ID
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT Marks.Student_ID AS Year, SUM(Final_Mark)/COUNT(Marks.Student_ID) AS Year_3_Marks
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Marks.Year_Taken = 3 AND Students.Student_ID IN
(SELECT Marks.Student_ID
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID) 
GROUP BY Marks.Student_ID
```

I would like for the output to be Separated into 3 columns, these being Student_ID, Year_1_Marks, Year_3_Marks. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not your personal help forum, but a repository of knowledge for everyone. Don't remove your question's content when it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KevinKevin

Your joins are not good practices.  Beware of "division by zero error" I've added.

Here is a example in "normal" SQL:

```
  SELECT
    Marks.Student_ID AS Year,
    (
      case when COUNT(case when Marks.Year_Taken = 1 then Marks.Student_ID else 0 end) <> 0 
      then SUM(
        case when Marks.Year_Taken = 1 then Final_Mark else 0 end
      ) / COUNT(
        case when Marks.Year_Taken = 1 then Marks.Student_ID else 0 end
      ) else 0 end
    ) AS Year_1_Marks,
    (
      case when COUNT(case when Marks.Year_Taken = 3 then Marks.Student_ID else 0 end) <> 0 
      then SUM(
        case when Marks.Year_Taken = 3 then Final_Mark else 0 end
      ) / COUNT(
        case when Marks.Year_Taken = 3 then Marks.Student_ID else 0 end
      ) else 0 end
    ) AS Year_3_Marks
  FROM
    Marks
    INNER JOIN Students ON Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID
  GROUP BY
    Marks.Student_ID
```

Here is a example in "Access" SQL:

```
  SELECT
    Marks.Student_ID AS Year,
      Iif ( COUNT(Iif( Marks.Year_Taken = 1 ,Marks.Student_ID, 0))=0,0,
       SUM(Iif ( Marks.Year_Taken = 1,Final_Mark, 0) ) / COUNT(Iif( Marks.Year_Taken = 1 , Marks.Student_ID, 0)) 
    ) AS Year_1_Marks,
      Iif ( COUNT(Iif( Marks.Year_Taken = 3 , Marks.Student_ID, 0))=0,0,
       SUM(Iif ( Marks.Year_Taken = 3 Final_Mark, 0) ) / COUNT(Iif( Marks.Year_Taken = 3 , Marks.Student_ID, 0)) 
    ) AS Year_3_Marks,

  FROM
    Marks
    INNER JOIN Students ON Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID
  GROUP BY
    Marks.Student_ID
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick reply and your help! After I made a few changes this worked like a charm!  Just out of curiosity, what did you mean when you said my joins are bad practices (I'm relatively new to this and don't want to pick up any bad habbits)?

Comment: About bad practices.Your `Where` clause was very strange. You've called Marks and Students table in the `FROM` and you've called again in the `WHERE .. IN()` clause. In other words `select * from T1,T2 where T1.a=T2.a` (old SQL) or `select * from T1 inner join T2 on T1.a=T2.a` (ansi SQL 92) are good and normal practices. Rather your `select * from T1,T2 where T2.a  in  (select  T1.a FROM T1, T2 Where T1.a=T2.a )` was very weird. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a join.  I would make some changes to your code for maintainability and possibly performance but just to give you the idea, this should work.

```
Select A.Student_ID, A.Year_1_Marks, B.Year_3_Marks
   From (
SELECT Marks.Student_ID AS Year, SUM(Final_Mark)/COUNT(Marks.Student_ID) AS Year_1_Marks
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Marks.Year_Taken = 1 AND Students.Student_ID IN
(SELECT Marks.Student_ID
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID) 
GROUP BY Marks.Student_ID
) A
Join (
SELECT Marks.Student_ID AS Year, SUM(Final_Mark)/COUNT(Marks.Student_ID) AS Year_3_Marks
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Marks.Year_Taken = 3 AND Students.Student_ID IN
(SELECT Marks.Student_ID
FROM Marks, Students
WHERE Students.Student_ID = Marks.Student_ID) 
GROUP BY Marks.Student_ID
) B On B.Student_Id = A.Student_Id
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick reply! The code you posted returned an error (Syntax Error in FROM Clause) but that was easily fixed by changing JOIN into INNER JOIN. It did however produce the additional issue of SQL not recognizing the values for A.Student_ID and B.Student_ID. So essentially, when I run the amended code a table pops up and asks me to pick a parameter value for A.Student_ID and B.Student_ID I do have student ID's and when I enter one of them it does give me the correct results (awesome!). I just need to figure out how to specify those two values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, correct your formating a bit so its a bit more readable.

Then you can try this, I think it should work fine:

```
 SELECT Students.Student_ID as Student_ID
      , SUM(marks1.Final_Mark)/COUNT(marks1.Student_ID) AS Year_1_Marks
      , SUM(marks3.Final_Mark)/COUNT(marks3.Student_ID) AS Year_3_Marks   
   FROM Students   LEFT JOIN Marks marks1
     ON marks1.Student_ID = Students.Student_ID
     AND marks1.Year_Taken = 1   LEFT JOIN Marks marks3
     ON marks3.Student_ID = Students.Student_ID
     AND marks3.Year_Taken = 3
```

This shows marks for all students, so if you have students with no marks, I would add a WHERE clause to exclude them to avoid any issues and such.